# java.lang.ClassCastException: JobEntity cannot be cast to JobExcerpt (using Spring Data Projections)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Using projections to get specific fields for Entity class JobEntity, using JobExcerpt.

***JobEntity class***: https://pastebin.com/GPeQDiRp

***JobExcerpt class***:

```
@Projection(
        name = "jobProjection",
        types = { JobEntity.class })
public interface JobExcerpt {
    Long getId();

    JobEntity.Status getStatus();

    List<BatchEntity> getBatches();

    Date getCreatedOn();

    Long getRetailerId();
}
```

Very simple ***JobExcerptRepository class***:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = JobExcerpt.class)
public interface JobExcerptRepository extends JpaRepository<JobEntity, Long> {

    JobExcerpt findByIdAndRetailerId(Long jobId, Long retailerId);

}
```

The line of code it fails on:

```
JobExcerpt jobExcerpt = jobExcerptRepository.findByIdAndRetailerId(jobId, retailerId);
```

The thing is... There is no visible (cast) like operator in this line of code. It shouldn't be displayed, right?

***Stack Trace***:
https://pastebin.com/iNG8h5dn

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you retrun a JobExcerpt Projection . That's why you got ClassCastException. It Should be like this.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = JobExcerpt.class)
public interface JobExcerptRepository extends JpaRepository<JobEntity, Long> {

    JobEntity findByIdAndRetailerId(Long jobId, Long retailerId);

}
```

```
JobEntity jobEntity = jobExcerptRepository.findByIdAndRetailerId(jobId, retailerId);
```

Comment: Would that JobEntity contain all the fields that the actual JobEntity class contains when called upon?

Comment: yes it will @NeilSouza because An excerpt is a projection that is automatically applied to a resource collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get come specific field from your domain. Then you can simply these thing.

```
// JobExcerpt.java

public interface JobExcerpt {

    Long getId();

    Status getStatus();

    List<BatchEntity> getBatches();

    Date getCreatedOn();

    Long getRetailerId();
}
```

```
//  JobExcerptRepository.java
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = JobExcerpt.class)
public interface JobExcerptRepository extends JpaRepository<JobEntity, Long> {

    JobExcerpt findByIdAndRetailerId(Long jobId, Long retailerId);

}
```

```
JobExcerpt jobExcerpt = jobExcerptRepository.findByIdAndRetailerId(jobId, retailerId)
```

Comment: You submitted two answers, this one says use JobExcerpt as return type in the repository and the above you say use JobEntity because an Excerpt is applied to the resource collection?... @pawan-maurya

Comment: and this solution is what i'm currently doing...which gives me the ClassCastException